# ASP.NET Core ASW S3 - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, amazon-s3, model-view-controller

I am getting this error when I try to upload a file to the bucket.

This is my code.

```
 public async Task UploadFileAsync(IFormFile file, string userId)
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
        var bucketName = this.configuration.GetSection("Amazon")["BucketName"];
        var accessKey = this.configuration.GetSection("Amazon")["AWSAccessKey"];
        var secretKey = this.configuration.GetSection("Amazon")["AWSSecretKey"];
        var bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;

        var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, bucketRegion);

        try
        {
            var fileTransferUtility =
                new TransferUtility(s3Client);

            using (var newMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.CopyTo(newMemoryStream);

                var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    InputStream = newMemoryStream,
                    Key = file.FileName,
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                };

                await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
            }

            await this.filesRepository.AddAsync(new FileBlob
            {
                Name = file.FileName,
                Extension = file.FileName.Split('.')[1],
                Size = file.Length,
                UserId = userId,
                UploadedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
            });
            await this.filesRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Razor:** [here](https://res.cloudinary.com/dnonuly2u/image/upload/v1590328344/Screenshot_1_l3oqil.png)

It always says "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the mistaken accessKey and secretKey. After I got them right all I had to do is change the **CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl**. That solved it for me